# Looking for literature on correcting one DEM with another

Tags: dem, references

I am looking for some scientific papers (any language) according how to deal with the correction of one DEM with a other (such as ASTER with SRTM). Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by correct?

Comment: Elevation errors and holes

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this article:

> CORRECTING DEM EXTRACTED FROM ASTER STEREO IMAGES BY COMBINING 
>   CARTOGRAPHIC DEM
>
> ABSTRACT:  The Advanced Spaceborne Thermal Emission and Reflection
>   Radiometer (ASTER) on-board the NASA's Terra spacecraft provides
>   along-track digital stereo image data at 15m resolution with a
>   base-height ratio 0.6. Automated stereocorrelation procedure was
>   implemented using the ENVI 4.1 software to derive DEMs with 15m×15m in
>   43 ㎞ long and 50㎞ wide area using the ASTER stereo images. The cloud
>   areas and cloud shadow areas removed on the ASTER DSM were replaced
>   with those areas detached from the digital topographic map DEM by band
>   math. The accuracy of DEMs was analyzed in comparison with those which
>   were obtained from digital topographic maps of 1:25,000 scale. Results
>   indicate that RMSE in elevation between ±7 and ±20m could be achieved.
>   Excluding cloud, water and building areas as the factors which make
>   RMSE value exceeding 10m, the accuracy of DEMs showed RMSE of 5.789m.

http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVII/congress/1_pdf/143.pdf